# Distance between two sample quantiles

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, st.statistics, measure-concentration

Let $X_1,\dots X_n$ be i.i.d. samples from an unknown distribution. We know the distribution has uniformly bounded probability density function $f(x)$. Let $1>\tau_1>\tau_2>0$ be two quantile levels and $\hat{X}^{\tau_1}$ and $\hat{X}^{\tau_2}$ be the corresponding sample quantile points. Note that the sample quantile is not unique. Now I want to give a sharp bound for the distance
\begin{equation}
  |\hat{X}^{\tau_1}-\hat{X}^{\tau_2}|.
\end{equation}
This problem also has a special case like the finding distance between two neighboring quantiles (i.e. $\tau_1-\tau_2=1/n$).

For simplicity we may assume $X_i$'s all sampled from standard normal distribution. So my question is, are there any elegant proofs for this problem? I would be grateful if somebody provide any reference about concentration results for median-type estimators.

Comment: I think you are looking for the results on the distribution of order statistics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thanks, but I think I need sharper inequalities, like exponential-type inequality or even Bahadur representation, the results like variance is not enough

Comment: Would an asymptotic bound serve your needs ?